# how to access db context within a static method/class in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have an asp.net core 2 webapplication with EF 6. The way I have been using db context so far is using dependency injection provided by asp.net core to inject the context into controllers:

```
protected DbContext dbContext;

public BaseController(DbContext context)
{
    dbContext = context;
}
```

In many of my razor views, I call an extension method to initialize a telerik grid, passing it options. So far I have not needed to access the db context, but now I need to access it in the extension method for some logic:

```
    public static GridBuilder<T> BaseProcessGrid<T>(this GridBuilder<T> helper, string controllerName, string gridName)
       where T : class, IProcessViewModel
    {
        bool showDelete = false;

        //check if the current user has edit rights 
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            var users = db.Users.ToList(); // <--- this just doesn't get any records.
        }
```

When trying to instantiate a new db context from within the static method, it just doesn't fetch any records. I need to figure out how to actually access a new instance of the DbContext, or somehow access the scoped service defined in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped(_ => new MantleMapperContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext")));
```

EDIT:

As suggested below, I ended up injecting the dbContext service directly into my view and then passing it into the method like so:

```
@inject DbContext dbContext
```

Comment: I would suggest creating a View component that builds an `OptionModel` for your extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass in your `DbContext`, or get an *instance* from the *container* which you will in-turn need a static reference too (this would fail most code reviews).

Doing what you are doing, it's initialising without the  *connection string* as that is plumbed up when it's injected.

Since this is `static` the neatest solution is to just pass in the `DbContext`.

```
public static GridBuilder<T> BaseProcessGrid<T>(this GridBuilder<T> helper, DbContext db, string controllerName, string gridName)
   where T : class, IProcessViewModel
{
    bool showDelete = false;

    var users = db.Users.ToList(); // <--- gets records.
```

**Update**

> how would i do that from within the razor view?

I believe you can inject services into views.

[Service injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> A service can be injected into a view using the @inject directive. You
> can think of @inject as adding a property to the view, and populating
> the property using DI.

Comment: how would i do that from within the razor view?

Comment: ok but then how can I access the service provider or the container?

Comment: @riz did that website help you out?